# How to scroll much further back in Linux Server running Bash

Tags: bash, scrolling, buffer, linux-terminal, linux-server

I am running Bash on the default terminal of a Debian Server (no GUI). I use `Shift` + `Fn` + `Up` key combination to scroll back but cannot view past a certain point. How do I achieve extended (or indefinite) scrolling?

Comment: I think this limit depends on the terminal software you are using, `bash` is not the terminal. Output is only temporarily buffered by the terminal software, but if you are using something like `gterm` or `screen` you can configure the history size.

Comment: @Romen I have a freshly installed system **without a desktop environment** and have not installed any new terminals, therefore I assume I am using the default one.

Comment: In any case, it's not possible to scroll further back than the limit of the terminal software you are using. Increasing that limit will not recover lost output lines.